# Navigate to local file Uri from silverlight? Exception

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

When i click button in SL app i want to open URI to local file in browser.When browser will navigate to this URI a "browser popup dialog" will appear to ask me if i want to "open-save-save as" this file.

I created a pure SL 4 application.Added button.In button click handler i wrote:

**HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("file://C:/Temp/Report.doc",UriKind.Absolute));**

I also tried to write it as

**HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri("file://C:/Temp/Report.doc", UriKind.Absolute), null, null);**

In either cases i have exceptions.

When i manually paste file://C:/Temp/Report.doc in InternetExplorer everything is fine, dialog appears on screen.

Is it possible to do such thing in Silverlight?

Answer (score 3):

A security exception will be thrown because Silverlight can't access your local machine's `C:\`. If you want to open a file, you can use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). However, in Silverlight 4, you can [access the filesystem](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/16/silverlight-4-s-new-local-file-system-support.aspx) if your application is `out of browser`.